# Recent Posts Not Showing Only On A Specific Category Page

Tags: php, wp-query, categories, theme-development

On my blog, for some reason, one of the category pages refuses to load new posts even when I clear all my caches. I'm using `WP Super Cache` (W3 Total Cache broke my site), `Autoptimize` and `Cloudflare` for caching.

I doubt the code is the problem since the other category pages are working just fine.

```
$query= new WP_Query(array(
    'offset' => 1,        
    'cat' => $cat_ID      
));

 if ( $query->have_posts() ) while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

 get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); // loaded from content.php

 endwhile;
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: I was determined to upvote this question the very first moment I saw it.

Comment: If you open your page from incognito browser window what you get?

Comment: Does it show any posts at all on that category page? If so, how many posts is it missing at the start? Trying to understand what you mean by load "new" posts...

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark honestly, but the offset may be causing it to not read that category in the category array. Maybe try turning the offset value to 0 (possibly even -1). Hope that helps. Good Luck.

EDIT: Also was able to find this with some information on the offset parameter:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'offset' from query argument.